# Expression Encoder ScreenCaptureJob not recording

Tags: c#, selenium, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk, expression-encoder-4

Hi I was wondering if anyone would have a solution to my problem here?

I have started to use ScreenCaptureJob in my TestAutomation Framework and found that for some reason, although it may work I find that if I leave my PC logged in for the very next day for some reason it will stop working. Here is the source code for reference. This issue is resolved by restarting, but remains consistent; i.e. the very next day if I haven't restarted it will persist...

[image: Source Code]

**Further info:**
scj.Status = NotStarted;

Also note that I have commented out the if statements and date handling logic to yield the exact same result, so this isn't what's causing the issue;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was to do with 2 active graphics cards, can easily disable one of them through device manager. Can easily find the correct exception by running Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 Screen Capture.exe and attempting to record through UI.